# Does IOUtils.copy block until writing is finished?

Tags: java, file, filesystems, apache-commons, nfs

Here's my situation: I'm using `IOUtils` to copy a file.  The next thing I do is send a JSON message to another program to say, "You can download the copy".  The problem is about 25% of the time the other program gets an error saying "Received unexpected EOF downloading artifact".

Every time this error occurs, if I try again manually, the error doesn't occur.  My theory is that `IOUtils.copy` doesn't block and the OS is still writing the file to the FS while the other program tries to download it.  Is there a way to force `IOUtils.copy` or other functionally equivalent code to block until the OS has finished writing the file?  Or is my theory incorrect?  Here's the code I'm using:

```
private boolean archiveArtifact(String archivePath, String deployId, Artifact artifact) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    boolean successful = true;

    try {
        File archiveDir = new File(archivePath);
        File deployDir = new File(archiveDir, deployId);

        if (!deployDir.exists()) {
            deployDir.mkdirs();
        }

        URLConnection connection = new URL(artifact.getJenkinsUrl()).openConnection();
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        File output = new File(deployDir, artifact.getFileName());
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        successful = false;
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            successful = false;
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            successful = false;
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    return successful;
}
```

It might be worth noting that I'm copying this to a NFS.  Keep in mind I don't really know anything about NFS.  This is CentOS release 5.9 (Final).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code only ensures that the file content is passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that it is actually written to a the disk.

To be certain that the file is actually written to disk you can call `sync()` on the `FileDescriptor`:

```
fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.getFD().sync();
```

Comment: OK thanks, I'll try that out and see if the problem goes away.